# How to Deserialize the dictionary and fetch the value of a particular key

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

How should I get the value of status key ?

```
string a = "\"[{\\\"Status\\\":\\\"Passed\\\"}]\""
```

tried with **JObject.Parse** and **JArray.Parse** to deserialize it and fetch the value.
getting error all the time, even if the key is present.

PS: this value is coming directly from the DB, where it is stored as a string.

Comment: Right, so if you unpeel the escaping, the *value* is actually `"[{\"Status\":\"Passed\"}]"`, which is *itself* an escaped string. That's almost certainly an error, but you could deserialize it with (e.g.) `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string>("\"[{\\\"Status\\\":\\\"Passed\\\"}]\""))[0]["Status"]` (this is using `System.Text.Json`), as well as typed classes of course. The main thing is unescaping the value first.

Comment: Fix the bug instead of trying to parse the buggy string. That's not a JSON dictionary, it's something that's been serialized *three times** already. Fix the code that generated this string so it produces only `[{"Status":"Passed"}]`. JSON strings are strings, not some different type. Serializing a JSON string won't produce the original. It will produce a simple string with escaped special characters. No other application will be able to read this

Comment: `this value is coming directly from the DB, where it is stored as a string.` the data storage code has a critical bug then and produces bad data. Which database are you using? None requires escaping strings, but many offer direct JSON support that can be used to fix the bad data.

Comment: It's quite possible the data storage code is using string concatenation instead of parameterized queries so it double and triple escapes double quotes just to create a valid SQL statement. Once again, that covers up the problem instead of fixing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Text.Json;

string a = "\"[{\\\"Status\\\":\\\"Passed\\\"}]\"";
var json = JsonDocument.Parse(a).RootElement.GetString();
var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
var dic = jDoc.RootElement[0].Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>();
var status = dic["Status"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better solution. But you can `remove the /` character and `split by "`

```
string a = "\"[{\\\"Status\\\":\\\"Passed\\\"}]\"";
var val=a.Replace("\\", "").Split(new string[] { "\"" },
StringSplitOptions.None)[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method can get the value, hope it can give you some help.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string a = "\"[{\\\"Status\\\":\\\"Passed\\\"}]\"";
var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(a);
var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(b.ToString());
```

[image]